# php notification

Tags: php

how to make a notification code in php?
when user make a booking request
how to notify admin that there were incoming booking request?

Comment: Well there are a lot of ways to do this... I would think e-mail notifications would be the way to go. Alas your question is too ambiguous, and doesn't note a system or framework it would exist in. This question cannot be answered as it is too open to debate and discussion.

Answer (score 2):

There are several possibilities, including:

- Send an email notification to a known address
- Use a database trigger to populate a view that the admin user will see on their app's page
- Write a message to a queue (such as AMQP) that will be read by another application.